# Troubles with creating parser

Tags: php, parsing

I've tried to use examples that I've found on Internet.. and they didn't work.

```
<?php
$sUrl = 'https://www.google.cz/';
$sUrlSrc = getWebsiteContent($sUrl);

// Load the source
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($sUrl);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

echo $xpath->query("/html/body[@id='gsr']/div[@id='viewport']/div[@id='main']/span[@id='body']/center/div[@id='lga']/div/div[@id='hplogo']");
?>
```

This should get this text: Česká republika. But nothing happends.
PHP Ver: 5.3

Comment: You just queried the DOM but you must get to the element and after that, query for the element content (text) (depending what kind of element is it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your code didn't throw a fatal error when you attempt to `echo $xpath->query(...);` indicates that your `DOMXPath` object isn't valid (see #2 below); if that's not valid, the actual `DOMDocument` isn't valid which means it's not able to load the data you're pointing too (i.e. `https://www.google.cz`).

If this is true then it is most likely because your current PHP setup does not have the `php_openssl` extension enabled. Without it, PHP won't know how to load the `https` wrapper and will fail to load the data.

To verify, make sure you have error reporting enabled with the following (just place them at the top of your script):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

After enabling the `php_openssl` extension, you should run into two additional errors:

1. The xpath query you've written is very complex (and actually not correct; I haven't verified what the "correct *full* path" is, however, your current one doesn't bring back results). Instead, you can leverage the fact that the node you're after has an `id` attribute which is supposed to be unique:

   ```
   $nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@id="hplogo"]');
   ```
2. You cannot simply echo the return value of `DOMXPath::query()`; doing so will result in a fatal error of `Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string`. Instead, you can do either of the following:

   ```
   // if you expect multiple values
   $nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@id="hplogo"]');
   foreach ($nodes as $node) {
       echo $node->nodeValue . '<br />';
   }

   // or

   // if you expect a single value
   $node = $xpath->query('//div[@id="hplogo"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
   echo $node;
   ```

Comment: Thanx, my hosting had php_openssl disabled.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
<?php
$sUrl = 'https://www.google.cz/';
$sUrlSrc = file_get_contents($sUrl);

// Load the source
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($sUrl);

$xpath = @new DomXPath($dom);

echo $xpath->query("//div[@id='hplogo']")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Note that you don't need to go through the whole html to find a ID (which is always unique).

Comment: Thanx, my hosting had php_openssl disabled.